# AWS Oracle RDS backup / restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle

I have a huge Oracle Enterprise Edition RDS DB in AWS, aorund 6253 GB, that I will not used for some days. Is there a way to backup the DB and restore it after some days to avoid to pay (for the period I will not use the DB) the fee per GB-month of provisioned GP2 storage. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can stop your RDS instance (announced June 1, 2017) for up to 7 days. If you do chose to snapshot your database and delete, update this thread as I am very curious on how long the snapshot will take for 6.2 TB.

The stop/start feature is available for database instances running in a Single-AZ deployment which are not part of a Read Replica (both source and replica) configuration.

Amazon RDS for MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle and SQL Server now allows you to easily stop and start your database instances. This makes it easy and affordable to use databases for development and test purposes, where the database is not required to be running all of the time.

Stopping and starting a database instance requires just a few clicks in the AWS Management Console, or a single call using the AWS API or AWS Command Line Interface, and takes just a few minutes. While your database instance is stopped, you are charged for provisioned storage, manual snapshots and automated backup storage within your specified retention window, but not for database instance hours.

[Amazon RDS Supports Stopping and Starting of Database Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/)

Comment: I think this is probably the best option. This still leaves a storage fee of around $700 if it was stopped for a month. Using snapshots / backups isn't much cheaper - general purpose RDS storage is $0.115/GB month, backup storage is $0.095c/GB month, so on 5TB you'd save an additional $100 per month using snapshots rather than stopping the instance. That doesn't take into account any other backup / snapshot storage.

Answer (score 0):

AWS provides two ways to backup and restore Oracle RDS.

Automated Backups – This option is turned on by default. It allows point-in-time recovery for DB instance and will backup your database and transaction log. It stores both of them for a user-defined retention period. Due to this, you can restore DB instance anytime during the retention period, up to the last five minutes. You can configure the automatic backup retention period to up to 35 days.

DB Snapshots – This user-initiated backup option gets your full database stored by Amazon RDS until you delete them. It allows you to create a new DB Instance from a DB Snapshot anytime you want.

A third option is to use an AWS third party [backup solution](https://n2ws.com/product). These services provide a variety of backup options if you need a less hands on solution.  Yes, there is a cost; but the ROI depends on your particular business needs.